# Java servlet deployment error webui-jsf-suntheme

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, woodstock

I am receiving the following run-time error in the web browser (Firefox) when attempting to run a deployed Java servlet on a Linux server:

```
unterminated string literal

dojo.provide("webui.suntheme.browser");w...wGroupsContainer,_41f.rowGroups[i],"last
```

I believe the problem is related to webui-jsf-suntheme.  I can confirm that the application successfully deploys on Windows and on a Linux virtual machine running the same versions of the JDK etc as the production server.  I have tried redeploying the application and restarting the server but with no success.

The server runs Debian, the servlet is deployed to **Tomcat 6.0** and the **Java version is 1.6.0_12-b04**.

Comment: This is using the Sun Woodstock library, right? There isn't much to go on here. Are you using any JS minification libraries like Jawr?

Comment: Sorry I haven't given much to go on - I didn't develop the app, I am just trying to deploy it.  I could only assume that it's using Sun Woodstock libraries but I wouldn't know how to tell for certain (I am not experienced in administering Java).

Comment: Is this a compiled war file, or a project that you are attempting to build and deploy?

Answer (score 0):

The application was developed using VisualJSF (Project Woodstock). This JSF 1.2 platform is no longer supported by Oracle. The project can be opened with NetBeans 6.7 (if it is VisualJSF), otherwise you would need to add the libraries directly to the project.